# Servidor TCP + Servidor Web na mesma aplicação

Tags: node.js, express.js

Seguinte pessoal, estou com algumas ideias de um projeto e estou com algumas dúvidas ...

1ª É possivel criar um Servidor TCP que vai tratar a conexão com o Cliente junto com um Web Server usando express que vai ter funções como start, stop e restart do servidor tcp?
2ª Se for possivel, eu devo fazer isso? Seria uma boa ideia colocar os dois na mesma aplicação ou é melhor separar as duas? (Levando em consideração que o servidor tcp ira ter muitos acessos)

3ª Existe uma estrutura ideal para as pastas e arquivos para um servidor tcp ? Posso aplicar o conceito MVC ? Se sim, a responsabilidade de criação do server tipo `net.createServer()` ficaria no controller ?

Obrigado,
Grande abraço.

Answer (score 1):

> É possivel criar um Servidor TCP que vai tratar a conexão com o Cliente junto com um Web Server usando express que vai ter funções como start, stop e restart do servidor tcp?

Sim, é possível. Para tanto você precisa inicializar um listener TCP:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer();  
server.on('connection', handleConnection);

server.listen(9000, function() {  
  console.log('server listening to %j', server.address());
});

function handleConnection(conn) {  
  // [...]
}
```

<sup>(Exemplo parcial de https://blog.yld.io/2016/02/23/building-a-tcp-service-using-node-js/#.WTYTdWjythE )</sup>

> 2ª Se for possivel, eu devo fazer isso?

Vai depender exclusivamente da sua modelagem. Você pode estar querendo escrever uma solução compacta, onde *listeners* HTTP + TCP podem co-existir - ou um uma implementação separada por serviços.

> 3ª Existe uma estrutura ideal para as pastas e arquivos para um servidor tcp? Posso aplicar o conceito MVC?

De novo, a resposta depende da sua modelagem. Eu confesso que tenho uma certa dificuldade em visualizar um modelo de pastas para uma solução TCP, já que estamos falado de um *stream*. Se você está se referindo às classes, aí é um outro papo.

Quando ao modelo MVC, sim, existem vários módulos NodeJS que adotam este modelo. Já que `net.createServer()` tem a ver com manutenção de estado, eu diria que sim, a camada do controller seria uma boa candidata a host das funcionalidades de controle de conexão.